# Different plots with show and savefig

Tags: python, histogram, spyder

I am plotting histograms with quite large number of bins. I am using Spyder, Python 3.6.3. The problem I found is that the figure I am seeing in iPython console is NOT the same as the saved plots. I have seen this [thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5cVW.jpg) which asks a similar question, however, my problem is worse, as it's not just the fonts and sizes that vary, I am actually getting different counts!

E.g. the same script:

```
plt.clf()
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
fig.dpi=100
plt.hist(df['POS'], bins=nbins, range=(0,dict_l[c]))

plt.savefig('current_chr17.jpg', dpi=100)
```

will produce this plot as a saved figure:
[image]
and show this in iPython console (interactive mode on, I'm not even asking for plt.show):
[image]

Does anyone have any explanation as to what is going on?

Comment: Is it possible that your data is varying? Between two plotting calls?

Comment: No. It is the same run of the job...

Comment: In your console you can have a variable with the same name as in the script, but with a different value

Comment: I would think that when I run the script which invokes the interactive plot, the variables will be over-written by the script? Anyway, I just checked it to be sure. Removed all variables from console and re-run the script. The results are the same as before - i.e. different in a saved figure and in console.

Comment: The variables are not generally overwritten. When you press "Ctrl + F6" and enable "Execute in current console", then you should be able to interact with the variables with the same name in the current console. Then the plots should be the same, because they use the same data.